Ubuntu 24.04 Installation problem
I try to install Ubuntu 24.04 and it seems that the process is stopped in Copying Files...
Should I do a hard restart  to my PC ?

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 20.04 runs OK from USB but it takes too long to install on the HDD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
